# Why do my Rspec tests fail after Rails 4 upgrade?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I recently upgraded my Rails application to Rails 4 and in my Rspec test suite one line is causing an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   TypeError: can't cast Array to string: INSERT INTO "items" ("created_at", "date", "description", "invoice_id", "position", "price_in_cents", "quantity", "tax_rate", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

This is my code:

```
# /spec/controllers/invoices_controller_spec.rb:

require 'spec_helper'

describe InvoicesController do

  before :each do
    ...
    @invoice = FactoryGirl.create(:invoice, :project_id => @project.id, :user => @user, :items_attributes => [ FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:item) ]) # causing havoc
  end

  ...

end
```

---

```
# /spec/factories.rb:

factory :invoice do
  number 123
  recipient { Faker::Name.name }
  date { Time.zone.now.to_date }
  association :user
  association :project
  factory :invoice_with_item do
    items { |i| [i.association(:item)] }
  end
end
```

Can anybody tell me what I am missing here?

I guess it's somehow related to the fact that the `Invoice` class accepts nested items.

Comment: Do we get to know what the problem actually is? 'Causing havoc' isnt very descriptive.

Comment: Why don't you user invoice_with_items?? invoice = FactoryGirl.create(:invoice_with_items, :project_id => project.id, :user => user)? anyway, as sevenseacat said, "causing havoc" doesn't help anyone

Comment: @sevenseacat: OK, added the error message above.

Comment: Probably because item_attributes should be a hash, not an array. Like when being submitted from a form. Without a full error, hard to say.

Comment: @sevenseacat: No, it should be an array. It worked like that in Rails 3 and changing it to a hash throws a syntax error here.

Comment: No, it should be a hash. When submitting it from a form, it will be in the form `{0 => {property1: value, property2: value}, 1 => {property: value}}`.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem may have something to do with the Faker Gem, although i don't think it would looking at your code. I'm not sure what has changed in rails4 that would cause any problems with Faker (or factory_girl for that matter)

I had a factory like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job, :class => Job do
    ...
    password        { Faker::Lorem.words()[0..38] }
    ...
  end
end
```

This caused the same error (only in rails 4 - worked fine in 3) until I changed it to "Faker::Lorem.words().join()[0..38].to_s"

Comment: Thanks for this post I wasn't aware it would return an array. This helped me a lot.

Comment: oh thank you! the password attribute requires a string, but the words method returns an array. Thus if it is cast into a string, all will be well.